# How to retrieve Top 2 rows from each group in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem is simple to understand. I just need to know a formula that will help find a way to fetch the top 2 rows of each group in an excel sheet.

The below example is grouped by column 1.

Example

Given Table:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | A102012 |
| Apple | A102013 |
| Apple | A102014 |
| Banana | A102015 |
| Banana | A102016 |
| Banana | A102017 |
| Coconut | A102017 |

Result:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | A102012 |
| Apple | A102013 |
| Banana | A102015 |
| Banana | A102016 |
| Coconut | A102017 |

Comment: I think that the `=LARGE()` function is what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something that works with alphanumeric too. I change the above table. You are right but it only works with numbers. @Dominique

Comment: `LARGE()` would take the largest value @Dominique. Not the top two rows of each unique value. I do see why you mentioned it though since the way the question reads is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=REDUCE(A1:B1,UNIQUE(A2:A8),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TAKE(FILTER(A2:B8,A2:A8=b),2))))
```

To mimic this for Google Sheets:

```
=REDUCE(A1:B1,UNIQUE(A2:A8),LAMBDA(a,b,{a;QUERY(A2:B8,"Where A='"&b&"' limit 2")}))
```

A much slower alternative is:

```
=FILTER(A:B,INDEX(COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)))<3)
```

Comment: SORTN() can be also used instead of QUERY() in case of Google sheet.

Answer (score 2):

A faster method than countifs not using most recent additions to Excel, if it can be assumed that data are pre-sorted:

```
=LET(count,COUNTA(A:A),Column1,A2:INDEX(A:A,count),Column12,A2:INDEX(B:B,count),FILTER(Column12,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(count-1),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,1,IF(INDEX(Column1,c)=INDEX(Column1,c-1),a+1,1))))<=2))
```

[image]

or in Google Sheets:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(Column12,filter(Column12,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(rows(Column12)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,1,IF(INDEX(Column12,c,1)=INDEX(Column12,c-1,1),a+1,1))))<=2))(filter(A2:B,A2:A<>"")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can also use this formula

```
=LET(rank,MAP(tblData[value],tblData[fruit],
          LAMBDA(v,f,SUMPRODUCT((tblData[fruit]=f)*(v<tblData[value]))+1)),
FILTER(tblData,rank<=2))
```

The `MAP` function calculates the rank of each row within its group.
Then we can filter by that list.

[image]